JDBC connection to PieCloudDB
I'm currently working on a project that involves integrating a Java application with a cloud-based database service.
I want to try using PieCloudDB and need to establish a connection to PieCloudDB using JDBC. But I only found a way to connect using python psycopg2, and no Java-related guide. I want to know how to implement it using Java.

PieCloudDB has an external connection tool PieProxy in its cloud native platform. PieProxy supports clients include psql, pgadmin, DBeaver, Navicat,etc. and drivers or packaging libraries include psycopg, JDBC, pgx, gorm, Mybatis, Hikari, etc.
After obtaining the host IP, port, database name, user name, token password and virtual data warehouse ID, you can use DBeaver and PostgreSQL JDBC Driver to connect PieCloudDB. Pay attention to filling in the virtual data warehouse ID in the options of Driver properties.
